# Storing custom data with Facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

I have a question. Is it possible in iOS Unity app to store some data (a couple of bool/int values) in Facebook using player account? And acces this data in another app? Maybe some plugins can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone still interested, I'm using Parse with Facebook extension

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to access and store some data within an external mySQL table or something similar. There are some free database hosting services online at the moment that you can take advantage of if you're at a budget.

This is really the only way you're going to be able to access it from other apps - although I could be wrong, if anyone else knows different, feel free to correct me.